# Kubernetes ingress Json patch failing

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kustomize

I am trying to Json patch an ingress with Kustomize but its failing

ingress patch:

```
- op: replace
  path: /spec/rules/http/paths/path/backend/serviceName
  value: varnish
- op: replace
  path: /spec/rules/http/paths/path/backend/servicePort
  value: 6091
```

Following is my ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: magento-web
  namespace: magento
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:eu-west-2:AccountID:certificate/aaccxsdssa-bbb-434f-b2f9dss-05xxxx51f30
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": {"Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
  labels:
    app: magento-web
spec:
  rules:
    - host: training-example.cloud
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: magento-web
              servicePort: 80
```

I tried to filter through items from ***spec*** but my patch is still failing. I think its something to do here  ***/spec/rules/http/paths/path/backend/serviceName***

kustomize.yaml

```
bases:
  - ../step-3
  - ../bases/varnish

patchesJson6902:
- path: patch/ingress.yaml
  target:
    group: networking.k8s.io
    version: v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    name: main
    namespace: magento

configMapGenerator:
- name: aux
  namespace: magento
  behavior: merge
  env: config/aux.env
```

Comment: Can you add your kustomization.yaml ?

Comment: Please check Kustomization.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules and paths are JSON-Arrays. So you need the number. I can recommend you a website like https://jsonpathfinder.com/ where you can paste your json and drill down to your fields.

This should work:

```
- op: replace
  path: /spec/rules/1/http/paths/0/backend/serviceName
  value: varnish
- op: replace
  path: /spec/rules/1/http/paths/0/backend/servicePort
  value: 6091
```

Comment: error: couldn't find target networking.k8s.io_v1beta1_Ingress|magento|~P|magento-web|~S for json patch

Comment: You have to adjust your kustomization.yaml to match the exact `header` of the ingress.yaml
`group:extensions
version: v1beta1`

Comment: Really appreciate this! it fixes the issue